# How do I set current schema by using ibm_db_dbi to connect database?

Tags: database, db2, read-sql

I've been trying to use ibm_db_dbi to connect the database and read table by pandas.read_sql.

After creating the connection, I use set_current_schema('mySchema') to set the current schema for myConnection, so that I don't need to specify the schema in front of every tables.

However, when I read table by using pd.read_sql(sql, myConnection), it always uses the username as the schema, not the scheme that I specified.

Is there a way to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Terry

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db2
import pandas as pd

myConnection = db2.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;",  " ", " ")

myConnection.set_current_schema('mySchema')

sql = ('SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE')

names = pd.read_sql(sql, myConnection)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the connection-string with the `;CURRENTSCHEMA=MYSCHEMA;`

This works for me with pandas and Db2.

Example

```
myConnection = db2.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;CURRENTSCHEMA=MYSCHEMA;",  " ", " ")
```

For people who use a DSN (instead of a connection string in the script), you can include this additional information as a database parameter (and DSN parameter) in your `db2dsdriver.cfg` file.